# Store Ordered Entities in Morphia/MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm in the process of learning Morphia/MongoDB, and I had a question regarding ordered entities. I haven't had much luck searching for existing questions on this subject.

For the sake of this question, I have three entities: `Job`, `JobStatus` and `JobPriority`.

JobStatus and JobPriority instances are defined on the fly by users. These entities are global values which individual Job entities will reference. Both JobStatus and JobPriority need to be orderable, and that order needs to be saved.

Instinctively, I started to approach this with the following setup (slimmed down for reading ease):

**First: The Ordered Entities**

```
@Embedded
abstract class OrderedEntity {
    @Indexed(value=IndexDirection.ASC, name="order_ndx", unique=true)
    Integer oderNdx;
}

@Embedded
class JobStatus extends OrderedEntity { ... }

@Embedded
class JobPriority extends OrderedEntity { ... }
```

**Second: Parent Entities to manage the sort order**

```
@Entity
abstract class OrderedEntityList<T extends OrderedEntity> {
    @Embedded
    List<T> entities;
}

@Entity
class JobStatusList extends OrderedEntityList<JobStatus> { ... }

@Entity
class JobPriorityList extends OrderedEntityList<JobPriority> { ... }
```

**Third: The Job**

```
@Entity {
    @Reference
    JobStatus status;

    @Reference
    JobPriority priority;
}
```

My plan was to create an instance of JobStatusList and JobPriorityList on startup, and then use a form in the UI that would let users insert embedded Status/Priority instances and define the order.

I'm convinced that this is the wrong way to go about this and wanted to get some input before I dug in too deep.

If I understand the Morphia annotations correctly, Job entities can't `@Reference` `JobStatus` or `JobPriority` values because `@Embedded` entities can't have a reference-able ID.

---

**Edit:**

Based on comments and answers, this question needs to be clarified.

I am creating a generic job tracking framework that can be adapted at runtime to fit a variety of business models.

`JobStatus` represents a user-defined state for each job. Ultimately, I want to be able to do things like query all 'COMPLETED' jobs, so I want to maintain a global list of `JobStatus` entries which can be generated and ordered by a user to fit their needs.

At any given time, a `Job` only references a single `JobStatus`, but when updating the status of a `Job`, I want to be able to select the next status in the workflow order from a list of predictable, user-defined values.

`JobPriority` is similar in that I want it to be a global list of ordered, user defined values, but in most cases a Job will only ever reference a single priority.

Again, I want to be able to query things like all 'EXPEDITED' Jobs.

I know I could achieve this without a list by just saving individual entities and updating an `orderNdx` field on all JobStatus and/or JobPriority whenever an existing list entry is moved, but I would like to be able to do so in a way that guarantees a unique value in `orderNdx`.

Comment: So each Job has many status and priorities, but each JobStatus references just one Job?

Comment: More accurately, there are many job status and job priority values, and each Job references just one. In the case of JobStatus, it's like a progression step. For example, a job would reference Ordered->Printed->Delivered as it progressed through the workflow

Comment: You can add unique indexes in Mongo to ensure unique combinations of fields like an SQL db. You can also index and query embedded fields like `{statuses: {label: 'Blah', idx: 3}}`

Answer (score 0):

Morphia lets you define embedded classes in a List to keep things ordered. So you have a very simple solution that should work for you:

```
@Embedded
class JobStatus {
  ...
}

@Embedded
class JobPriority {
  ...
}

@Entity
class Job {

   @Embedded
   List<JobStatus> statuses = new ArrayList<JobStatus>();

   @Embedded
   List<JobPriority> priorities = new ArrayList<JobPriority>();

   ...

}
```

This way to skip unnecessary collections in Mongo and keep the embedded together with the job so you avoid multiple round trips to the database reducing latency.

Comment: But, if I understand the annotations, Embedding JobStatus/JobPriority values in a job prevents them from being defined at a global level?

Comment: I suppose I could pass a copy of the global lists into a job and add a boolean `isSelected` to the instance within the Job, but that seems inefficient, and the embedded copy wouldn't be updated if changes were made at a global level.